# Static Facade in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have this basic code

```
public abstract class SquallDAO<T extends SquallBean> {

     List<T> _find(String whereClause, String sortColumn, Integer lowerLimit, Integer upperLimit) throws Exception { ... }

}

class UserDAO extends SquallDAO<User> { }
```

and I'd like to be able to stand up a static facade for in the base class SquallDAO.  In the derived class it works fine :

```
class UserDAO extends SquallDAO<User> { 
     public static SquallDAO getInstance() { if ( instance != null ) return new UserDao(); 
     } 

     public static find(...) { return getInstance()._find(...) }
}
```

but I have a lot of these methods and would like to move them all to some shared base class.

How can I achieve this?  I'm not married to this solution, just looking for a elegant way for a static facade and keep inheritance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method cannot be both static and overridable. And you cannot declare static methods in interface (for above reason). At least for all Java versions below 8 (thanks to Giovanni Botta for noticing that Java 8 now allows that).

If you managed to put `getInstance` and `find` in a common base class, as Java implements generic through type erasuse, you would have no way in `find` to get the proper subclass from where you will actually get the (singleton) instance.

The only way I know that allows to move those almost identical functions to a common base class would be to get rid of that singleton pattern and instead use dependency injection.

Say you have a class that currently uses `UserDAO.find`. You would declare an **object** in that class of type `SquallDAO<T>` that you initialize through DI, something like :

```
SquallDAO<T> dao;
// setter for DI omitted
...
List<T> l = dao.find(...);
```

That way you can correctly call `find` from a common base class (maybe a service ...), with Java being able to call the correct find implementation.

You will find more details on that in framework implementing the DI pattern like SpringFramework or in Java EE

Comment: You actually can declare a [static method in an interface in java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).